# shell forcing demonized program to start without output

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a script that is required to have an exit code of 0. Unfortunalty I cannot use an init.d or other startup script to control this this, so I must make this work.

Basically if I understand AWS's docs correctly (elastic beanstalk), I need be able to run the following two commands and exit with a 0 and provide no other output to stdout.

As the root user I need to cd to a particular dir and run these two commands:

```
pkill -f que
bundle exec que
```

In my actually script I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

su -s /bin/bash -c "cd /some/dir && nohup pkill -f que &>/dev/null &"
sleep 10
su -s /bin/bash -c "cd /some/dir && nohup bundle exec que &"
```

Which still causes this error to be raised:

```
returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Any tips for how to silently run those commands correctly?

---

I'm also looking at these for ideas: 
https://blog.eq8.eu/article/aws-elasticbeanstalk-hooks.html
http://www.dannemanne.com/posts/post-deployment_script_on_elastic_beanstalk_restart_delayed_job

But its still not clear to me how this is supposed to exit successfully

Comment: probably a supervisor https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to run all this within this environment :(

Comment: Does it make a difference if you append `exit 0` to the script?

Comment: Send stdout and stderr to /dev/null: ` COMMAND >/dev/null 2>&1`.  The try what @M.Becerra said, add an exit 0 at the end.

Comment: Why does your script run these commands in the background? Is this required?

Comment: @pcjr otherwise the script will never exit as `que` is demonized and runs in the foreground.

Comment: @M.Becerra no, oddly enough, I feel like the presence of anything in stdout is causing it to exit with an error.

Comment: `nohup` redirects stdout and stderr to `nohup.out` if they aren't already going to a file already. (Better than `nohup` is to use the shell builtin `disown`, but for the same reasons, that won't work as desired unless the disowned process has its file handles that would be otherwise pointed to the terminal redirected to file).

Comment: BTW, why in the world are you putting the `pkill` in the background if you want it to be complete before the `bundle exec` starts? Letting something finish before the next thing starts is *exactly* what foreground tasks are for. I can understand backgrounding the `bundle exec` (sorta; good practice would be to use a proper process supervision system -- upstart, runit, daemontools, launchd, etc -- instead of this kind of hackery), but `pkill` is a different matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but wouldn't this be easily solved by using two shell scripts? One with `cd`, `pkill`, and `bundle`. Call this script (foo.sh) something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
su -c ./foo.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null
exit 0
```